# How to restrict the negative lookahead in regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a string:

```
Symphony Veterinary Center                                                           

symphony care veterinary  

170 cort 96th St.,                                                                   
naib, NZ 10025                                                            
212-866-8000                                                                                                                                              

                We care yours like ours !!
```

I am trying [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/L8ZlXm/3):

```
((?i)^(?=.*?(?:veterinary|animal[^s]|hospital| care |pets?|clinic)) *(?:[^ \n\r:]+? +?){1,5}$)(?:(?![\s\S]*?(?:(?i)veterinary|animal|hospital|care |pets?|clinic))[\s\S]*?)(\d{2,}[\s\S]+?(?: [A-Z][A-Za-z] (?:\d+-)?\d+))
```

As per the regex, the first group should capture the hospital name and the second group will capture the address alone.

In this regex, I have a negative lookahead `(?![\s\S]*?(?:(?i)veterinary|animal|hospital|care |pets?|clinic))` in between the first group and the second group in order to make sure that no keywords like animal, pet, hospital come in between the first and second group.

But it only matches when I remove the `care` in the last line of the string. I don't know why the negative lookahead is checking till the end of the string instead of before group two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?:(?![\s\S]*?(?:(?i)veterinary|animal|hospital|care |pets?|clinic))[\s\S]*?)` pattern is rather cumbersome, but it seems you wanted to match any text up to the leftmost occurrence of `veterinary`, `animal`, `hospital`, `care`, `pet`, `pets` or `clinic`.

You need to fix that part of the regex like

```
(?:(?!veterinary|animal|hospital|care\ |pets?|clinic)[\s\S])*?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L8ZlXm/4)

The pattern will match any char (`[\s\S]`), as few as possible (`*?`) that does not start the char sequences in the `(?!veterinary|animal|hospital|care\ |pets?|clinic)` negative lookahead.

I also advise to format the pattern string (as in my demo) and use `Pattern.COMMENTS` modifier option (do not forget to escape any literal whitespace and `#` chars then).